Is this a typo in Gilbarg Trudinger?

I understand the first inequality, but when I try to calculate the integral using polar coordinates I get a missing $n$:
$$
\int_{B_R(x)}|x-y|^{n(\mu-1)}dy=\int_0^R \int_{\partial B_1(0)} r^{n(\mu-1)}r^{n-1}d\sigma dr=\omega_n \int_0^R r^{n(\mu-1)}r^{n-1}dr=\int_0^R r^{n\mu-1}dr=\omega_n\frac{R^{n\mu}}{n\mu}
$$
Am I missing something?

In G&T, $\omega_n= \vert B_1\vert$. Hence, $\vert \partial B_1\vert =n \omega_n $, so the extra $n$ cancels with the $n$ on the denominator.
